# Is having a public getLock() or getMutex() function an antipattern?

Tags: java, c++, concurrency, synchronization, anti-patterns

I once had the pleasure of trying to identify possible concurrency issues in a C++ codebase where I kept seeing a pattern something like this:

```
lock(obj.getLock());
obj.foo();
unlock(obj.getLock());
```

or worse:

```
public void bar(SomeObject obj)
{
   obj.foo;
}

lock(obj.getLock());
bar(obj);
unlock(obj.getLock());
```

Thus, I had to look at every place where foo() was called and trace up until I could verify that it was only reachable from a locked context. (Technically there was no explicit unlock because these were scoped locks, but you get the idea).

I cannot think of any reason why you would ever do this instead of having the SomeObj object be responsible for it's own locking via a private lock whenever foo is called like so:

```
public void foo()
{
   lock(myPrivateLock);
   whateverFooDoes();
   unlock(myPrivateLock);
}
```

This way I can reach the same assurances without having to trace anything. Even if you need to do an atomic operation on several classes at once, you can still make a utility that controls its own lock to do this. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to turn up any sources explaining when to use a public getLock(), nor any others calling it an antipattern.

Is there any time when you should/must provide a public getLock() function instead of using private locks?

Thanks

Comment: I'm particularly curious about the answer to this in C++ and/or Java, but I imagine the answer shouldn't vary much between object oriented languages.

Comment: Your suspicions are correct, it is almost certainly poor style. However, if you want to update more than one object in the same transaction, you will need to separate out the taking of locks from the operations (see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock). This is a rare use case in my experience.

Comment: Hmm... interesting. If I understand the example correctly, I think my solution would most likely be to just synchronize the assign_lunch_partner() function on a lock of its own instead of having it need to acquire individual employee locks, but I guess that would prevent some non-conflicting calls from executing concurrently.I suppose if we assumed there's a very large number of employees, and that assigning a lunch partner is a slow and complex operation for some reason, synchronizing the method could cause a major performance penalty.